# mongodb indexes not reduced after documents reduction

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-atlas

I have implemented an archival solution to move off stale documents from mongodb(atlas) to cold storage and archival job has archived 40% of documents stored in mongodb and collection data size got shrunk to 40% but the indexes size continues to be same and also the storage size remains same.

Comment: [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/compact/)

Comment: will running compact affect ongoing read and write operation? since this is live database.

Comment: Starting in v4.4, on WiredTiger, compact only blocks the following metadata operations:

db.collection.drop()
db.collection.createIndex() and db.collection.createIndexes()
db.collection.dropIndex() and db.collection.dropIndexes()
compact does not block MongoDB CRUD Operations for the database it is currently operating on.

Comment: I am on mongodb v4.0.27 and mongodb documentation says compact will block all the operations to the database. What is the best practice to run a compact on 1+2(replicas) node ?

Comment: Take a replica down, run it again, this time as a standalone (see this manual: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/perform-maintence-on-replica-set-members) run the compaction, then rerun the instance again - this time as a replica set member.
Repeat the operation for the second replica.
Step down the master, wait till it turns to a replica, repeat the process again